# JAVA EE Application server in Desktop app?

Tags: swing, tomcat, quarkus, desktop

I´m currently looking for a solution to write a JSF application inside a Desktop app.
I think I can use:

- Start Main function
- Start SWING application
- Start JAVA EE application server
- Start database (e.g. H2 database)

I found the following solution with Tomcat:
https://www.beyondjava.net/how-to-wrap-bootsfaces-or-jsf-in-general-as-a-native-desktop-application

This is exactly which I would like to have. The only problem is, that Tomcat needs approx. 20 seconds to start.
Is there any other Application server which I can integrate like this in the Main class which will start than the Web application inside the SWING Gui?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general, putting a full-fledged JavaEE application inside of a desktop application is a bad idea. You have only one user working on a local machine, and the JavaEE platform is intended to be used in a concurrent environment to process multiple parallel requests coming from different clients over the Internet. A lot of facilities and trade-offs inside the JavaEE platform are implemented to support this. Using it to serve a single user on their local machine is like hammering nails with a microscope.

This is also a clear contradiction between your goal (quick startup of the desktop application) and trade-offs of a JavaEE application (the startup time doesn't really matter so much, as restarts happen rarely).

It's also worth to say that Tomcat is not a JavaEE server, as it doesn't provide the full JavaEE implementation. Although you definitely can run JSF applications on it by providing a JSF implementation inside the application itself.

If you really want to proceed, you could take a look at [jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) as a somewhat faster alternative to Tomcat.

Comment: so the other option would be to learn Java SWING?

Comment: Sure, if you need to write a Java desktop application, the first choice would be Swing. You could also take a look at [JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/) as a more modern way of writing complex desktop applications.

Comment: Is there also Drag & Drop WindowBuilder in eclipse e.g.?

Comment: Sure, you can use [WindowBuilder](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) to simplify the implementation of the UI.

Comment: Is this working also for JAVA FX? I can see it for Swing and AWT, but not JAVA FX

Comment: I think you'd have to post a different question if you have any issues with WindowBuilder specifically. In general, the questions of software recommendations are out of scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: ok, I have created a new topic... maybe someone can help